# I want to make datePicker on IOS by swift

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

all
I am a new developer on IOS. nowdays I study Swift by books.
there are some trouble. I use swift3 but the book consists of swift2.
so I don't know what is wrong code.
could you help me?
thanks you for reading and helping me.

this is datacode.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let timeSelector: Selector = #selector(ViewController.updateTime)
    let interval = 1.0
    var count = 0
    @IBOutlet weak var IbICurrentTime: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var IbIPickTime: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: interval, repeats: true, block: timeSelector)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func changeDatePicker(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
        let datePickerView = sender
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss EEE"
        IbIPickTime.text = "선택시간: " + formatter.string(from: datePickerView.date)
    }
    func updateTime() {
        IbICurrentTime.text = String(count)
        count = count+1
    }

}
```

there are problem

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: interval, repeats: true, block: timeSelector)
    }
```

i don't know what i have to input at "block"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Block" is the Objective-C term of Swift's closure. The "Blocks" variant works like this:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: interval, repeats: true, block: { timer in
    self.IbICurrentTime.text = String(self.count)
    self.count += 1
})
```

You don't need to define a separate `updateTime()` function with the block syntax.

In Swift the above can be written more naturally as

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: interval, repeats: true) { _ in
    self.IbICurrentTime.text = String(self.count)
    self.count += 1
}
```

---

If you want to use selectors, [use `scheduled​Timer(time​Interval:​target:​selector:​user​Info:​repeats:​)` instead](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timer/1412416-scheduledtimer):

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(time​Interval: interval,
                     target: self,
                     selector: #selector(updateTime),
                     userInfo: nil,
                     repeats: true)
```